# Is there a function that is continuous at every irrational but discontinuous at rational?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Does there exist a function $f$ such that it is discontinuous at rational and continuous at every irrational but the restriction on $f$ to the set of all irrational numbers is not constant and $f(q_n)$ is convergent where $\{q_n\}$ is a sequence of rationals.

Thomae function is one of an example of function that satisfies above condition if the restriction $f$ to the set of all irrational numbers is constant.

Comment: Do you mean that $f(q_n)$ is always convergent for any arbitrary sequence $\{q_n\}$ of rational number?

Comment: i don't think "convergence" suit this question

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $T(x)$ Thomae's function. Then
$$f(x)=T(x)+x$$
is a function satisfying your condition.